# Fetching the TenanId for a subscription from Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a requirement, where I needed to fetch the tenantDirectoryId for a given subscription.
I could find a rest get api https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/[subscription]/versions...

The error response to this gave the tenant directory.

Is there any better way to fetch directory for a subscriptionId.

Comment: Well.. since you are able to call the API I assume you have an access token. The token contains a `tid` claim which is the tenant id.

Comment: I am getting access token with my appId and hitting to common AAD directory.
While getting access token, subscriptionId is never passed.

Comment: Did you check the token? If you are able to use it, it must contain the tenant id.

Comment: It contains tokenId which is an identifier for the tenant the token was acquired from. But my requirement is to know the tokenId for any random subscription.

Comment: The api mentioned in your question is : `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription id>?api-version=2014-04-01` ?

Comment: Yes, basically I wanted to fetch tenantDirectory for any subscription.I get Unauthorised error since the token is not acquired from tenant AD.

Answer (score 2):

As of now (06/07/2018), an easy approach would be running az account show in the Azure Cloud Shell (requires a Storage Account) in the Azure Portal.

--- Command ---

```
az account show
```

--- Command Output ---

```
{
  "environmentName": "AzureCloud",
  "id": "{Subscription Id (GUID)}",
  "isDefault": true,
  "name": "{Subscription Name}",
  "state": "Enabled",
  "tenantId": "{Tenant Id (GUID)}",
  "user": {
    "cloudShellID": true,
    "name": "{User email}",
    "type": "user"
  }
}
```

See this doc for more details on Azure Cloud Shell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview

Answer (score 0):

We have recently had the same problem we wanted to fix. After speaking to Microsoft there is no supported way to do this through the Graph API when accessing as an application using the `client_credential`flow.

An approach we have taken to get the tenant id is to call the [OAuth2 metadata document endpoint for your tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oidc)

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

By calling this you’ll see your token endpoint as well as other useful information listed which you can utilise to log in. Or you can grab the tenant id using string stripping.